# pyodbc connection failure on linux

Tags: python, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am trying to connect to a database using pyodbc,following code is working fine on windows,trying to 
run the same on linux is giving an error as follows,can anyone suggest what is wrong here and how to fix it?

```
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
component_id=argv[1]
print "COMPONENT ID: " + component_id
server_name='odsdb.company.com'
database_name='ODS'
cnx = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server_name+";DATABASE="+database_name)
db_cursor=cnx.cursor()
```

vi /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[PostgreSQL ANSI]
Description             = PostgreSQL ODBC driver (ANSI version)
Driver          = psqlodbca.so
Setup           = libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug           = 0
CommLog         = 1
UsageCount              = 1

[PostgreSQL Unicode]
Description             = PostgreSQL ODBC driver (Unicode version)
Driver          = psqlodbcw.so
Setup           = libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug           = 0
CommLog         = 1
UsageCount              = 1
```

Error:-

```
  File "build_ver.py", line 11, in <module>
    cnx = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server_name+";DATABASE="+database_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 2434, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 2483, in connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 988, in check_success
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 964, in ctrl_err
pypyodbc.Error: (u'IM002', u'[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified')
```

Comment: what does your  `~/.odbc.ini` file look like?

Comment: @padraic - Downloading/unpacking odbc-postgresql
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement odbc-postgresql
No distributions at all found for odbc-postgresql

Comment: what linux dist are you using and what does `odbcinst -j` show from shell ?

Comment: [unixODBC 2.2.14
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /usr2/gnakkala/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8]

Comment: what linux dist? You need an ODBC driver

Comment: how to know what linux dist?odbcinst -j shows as unixODBC 2.2.14

Comment: which version of linux are you running it on?

Comment: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.2 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"

Comment: `sudo apt-get install odbc-postgresql` does not work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  - am able to install odbc-postgresql but still the same error

Comment: add the contents  of  `~/.odbc.ini` again to your questionm it should be different and also `/etc/odbcinst.ini
`

Comment: added /etc/odbcinst.ini ,i dont have ~/.odbc.ini

Comment: use `PostgreSQL ANSI` for Driver

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - sorry ,i am not clear on how to use PostgreSQL ANSI,do I have to isntall anytihng,can you please be more specific?

Comment: replace SQL Server with PostgreSQL ANSI

Comment: now i get a new errror as -------->pypyodbc.DatabaseError: (u'08001', u'[08001] [unixODBC]could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "odsdb.company.com" (10.43.32.211) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n

Answer (score 0):

`sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`.

uncomment and change    `listen_addresses` from `localhost` to `*`

Next:

```
`sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`
```

change `127.0.0.1/32  to 0.0.0.0/0` 
    in the line:

```
 `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust`
```